# Autoencoder: accuracy & number of images

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am working with Python, Tensorflow and Keras to run an autoencoder on 450x450 rgb front-facing images of watches (e.g. [watch_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT4F7.jpg)). My goal is to use the encoded representation of these images which are generated by the autoencoder and compare these to find the most similar watches among them. For now, I am using 1500 rgb images as I do not have a GPU yet but only a pc with 26BG RAM.

My source code is the following:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from glob import glob
import sys

data = []
number = 1500
i = 0
for filename in glob('Watches/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    # Transpose images to one line
    if height == 450 and width == 450:
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        data.append(img)
    else:
        print('These are not the correct dimensions')

    i = i + 1
    if i > number:
        break

# Normalise data
data = np.array(data)
Norm = preprocessing.Normalizer()
Norm.fit(data)
data = Norm.transform(data)

# Size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 250

# Input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(width * height * channels,))
# Encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# Lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(width * height * channels, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# Autoencoder model in all
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# Compile the model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(autoencoder.summary())

# Train the model
length = len(data)
data_train = data[:int(0.7*length)]
data_test = data[(int(0.7*length) + 1):]

autoencoder.fit(data_train, data_train, epochs=10, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, validation_data=(data_test, data_test))
```

I am getting the following results in brief:

```
Epoch 1/10
loss: 0.6883 - acc: 0.0015 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_acc: 0.0015

Epoch 2/10
loss: 0.6883 - acc: 0.0018 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_acc: 0.0018

# I omit the other epochs for the sake of brevity  

Epoch 10/10
loss: 0.6883 - acc: 0.0027 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_acc: 0.0024
```

The accuracy is very low.

Is this because I use a relatively small number of images or because there is a problem with my source code?

If the problem is the number of images then how many images are needed to have accuracy > 80%?

Comment: Accuracy makes no sense in this context, you have a regression problem, the autoencoder is trying to predict continuous values. You should only look at the loss values (and maybe use MSE instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I want to elaborate more on my answer after reading the blog post you commented. Your implementation is actually correct, but you don't want to evaluate the autoencoder by alone by itself.

Autoencoders are thought of as dimension reduction processes, so whatever output the autoencoder generates, is always going to be lossy. You can evaluate how well the autoencoder works by adding it as a layer to your neural network that actually does the classification. What happens is that the lossy representations become "input" to your subsequent neural network. In this subsequent neural network, you want to use the `softmax` activation as the last layer. Then you can evaluate the accuracy of the NN.

Think of autoencoders as a preprocessing step for dimension reduction, similar to principal components analysis.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(autoencoder.layers[1])  # here is where you add your autoencoder
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))  # assumes 10 watch classes
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response (upvote). Your answer clarifies some interesting points but keep in mind that I simply followed the Keras blog about autoencoders (https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). In this respect, the question which naturally arises is why they were proposing these hyperparmeters...but perhaps this is because they did not have the similarity comparison with the autoencoders in their mind (?).

Comment: Secondly, can I achieve really good accuracy with this tuning or buying one powerful GPU will make things significantly better instantly?

Comment: @Universalis I updated my answer. A GPU will just make training faster. It won't affect accuracy.

Comment: That's a nice answer, thanks. I agree with you about the GPU but I think there is something more in it. A GPU will give me the memory space to use way more than 1500 images which will significantly improve the accuracy of the autoencoder so it is not exclusively a matter of speed. My problem is that I get a memory error when I use more than 1500 rgb images. Am I right in what I am saying or  not?

Comment: Well yes, GPU will give you the memory space because the GPU card will store some of the matrices in its memory, but in general deep neural networks will utilize a lot of resources.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Then how can I process, let's say, 20000 of 450x450 rgb images for my autoencoder? Would this require two GPUs or it is not necessary to use so many images for this task?

Comment: Shall I simply use small batches so that images can fit in the memory?

Comment: Yes, you set your batch size with `batch_size` when fitting. Default is batches of 32. :)

Comment: Ok, so if I have smaller batches then I can manage to process a very large amount of images with a neural network (even though small-batches take obviously more time) without getting any memory error? (Sorry but sometimes I want to make very clear even very trivial stuff)

Comment: Well, `batch_size` alone won't fix the memory problem. Based on your code, you are loading all images into a `data` list, which is where I foresee the issue. My recommendation is to either resize the images to smaller images and/or convert the rgb to grayscale so you are working with 1 channel.

Comment: Ok. Even though I am not so sure that 1500(images)*3(channels)*450(width)*450(height)=0.91 GB are at this point a problem. But if I want to use way more images e.g. 15000 then 9.1GB will be gradually short of a problem.  In this sense, `batch_size` seems to be my primary problem for now. Do you agree?

Comment: Also, I certainly thought of data augmentation (cropping, rescaling, grayscale etc) but I am not so sure if I am losing any valuable information with any of these things.